# Can I show both keyboard and input view while textField became first responder

Tags: ios, keyboard, textfield

I want to show a custom UIView above my keyboard, when my text field is becoming first responder.

However, it seems that I can show view and keyboard both at the same time?

Is there is a way to overcome it?

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    phoneInputTextField.becomeFirstResponder()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleKeyboardNotification), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame , object: nil)
}


  func handleKeyboardNotification(notification: NSNotification) {

    guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
        let frameValue = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue
        else { return }

    let customView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height:  frameValue.cgRectValue.width + 20))
    customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

    phoneInputTextField.inputView = customView

}
```

That code shows only keyboard.

Comment: First, the `.inputView` *replaces* the keyboard, so you can't show both at the same time anyway... do you actually want `.inputAccessoryView`?

Answer (score 3):

**You can use inputView and inputAccessoryView both.**

- inputView is used to assign a some custom view in replacement of UIKeyboard , like you can use UIPickerView , UIDatePicker etc while editing the textField
- inputAccessoryView is also used to assign a some custom view but without replacing a UIKeyboard , it renders above the keyboard . like you can use UIToolbar above the keyboard and many other View as per your requirements.

**In your case you can use inputAccessoryView**

**example :**

yourTxtField.inputAccessoryView = yourCustomView()